# PHP displaying unique data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

currently I have a website with a basic login, I was just wondering how I would display a the name,skill and description of the unique user who is logged in.This is what I have done so far.I can only find articles on how to display data into table.This is the updated code:

```
   <?php
   include('session.php');
   require 'config.php';
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile";
   $result = $conn->query($sql);
   //echo "id: " . $row["id"]. " - Name: " . $row["firstname"]. " " . $row["lastname"]. "<br>";
?>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="profile.css">

</head>

<body>



<ul>
  <li><a href="welcome.php">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="postjob2.php">PostJob</a></li>
  <li><a href="findjob.php">Find Job</a></li>
  <li><a href="hiw2.php">How It Works</a></li>
  <li><a href="notification.php">Notifications</a></li>
  <li><a href="message.php">Message</a></li>
  <li><a href="profile.php">profile</a></li>

</ul>

<h1>Welcome To Bid4MyJob</h1>
  <li><a href="editprofile.php">edit profile</a></li>

<div id="ProfilePage">
    <div id="LeftCol">
        <div id="Photo"></div>
        <div id="ProfileOptions">
        a
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="Info">
        <p>
            <strong>Name:<?php echo  $row["name"]?></strong>
            <!--<span>James</span>-->
        </p>
        <p>
            <strong>Skill:<?php echo $row["skill"]?><</strong>
            <!--span>James</span>-->
        </p>
        <!-- <p>
            <strong>review:<?php /*echo $row["review"]*/?><</strong>
            <span>james</span>
        </p> -->
        <p>
            <strong>Description:<?php echo $row["description"]?><</strong>
            <span>James</span>
        </p>
        <!--<p>
            <strong>Name:</strong>
            <span>james</span>
        </p>-->
    </div>

    <!-- Needed because other elements inside ProfilePage have floats 
    <div style="clear:both"></div>-->
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you populating `$row` with your mysql data?

Comment: That  is what I'm trying to do but it does not work and this wouldn't output it for the specific user?

Comment: Post the whole code.

Comment: If you have id of the logged in user - you can select his data from database.

Comment: You probably need a `where` clause on your query. Please add the code that is suppose to be populating `$row`.

Comment: name,skill and description is a column in a table in my database

Comment: Okay, that doesn't show how you are interacting with the DB though. It is likely you just need to add a where clause `from users WHERE userid = ?`. We can't help you though with the amount of code you've added. It is too minimal.

Comment: If you already know how to display such data in a table, where **exactly** is the problem? The logic to gather such data and the markup to display it can be changed independently

Answer (score 1):

when the user successfully loggedin create a cookie and store their username or email whatever you used in that cookie. You have to do this stuff in your login.php file where you checks for username and password.

```
     if(login success)
   {
    setCookie("username",value of username that you got from 
    user,'time()+3600','/');
    echo "login successful";
   }
```

After that in Profile you have write code like this;

```
    <?php
$name=$_COOKIE['username'];
$sql=$conn->prepare("SELECT * from profile where username=?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $name); // 's' specifies the variable type =>'string'

$stmt->execute();

$result = $stmt->get_result();
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // do something with $row
}
?>
```

After that you can display the inforamtion in your div like $row['username']  etc.

Comment: `username='$name'` is not safe to use. Also since the user has `include('session.php');` I'd assume they are using `$_SESSION`s already, which would be better than the cookie.

Comment: ya we have to use Prepared statement query.

Comment: You should add that to the answer.

Comment: but the session will be destroy if the user closes the browser so we have to use session and cookies both.

Answer (score 0):

if $row[] come from a sql request, just add in your request something like :

```
$user = (...) your current user logged
(...)
select (...) where user = $user
```

Comment: ok I see but how will I identify the current user who is logged in?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$_SESSION` to identify people after login and store information about the person. A session variable saves data of a specific user across multiple pages.
A session id is stored in the user browser and that is used to identify the `$_SESSION` data of a person.
In your program you can easily do something like this:

```
 <?php
  session_start(); //before anything else
  include('session.php');
  require 'config.php';
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM profile";
  $result = $conn->query($sql);
  //assuming $row contains the information from 
  $_SESSION["user"] = $row;
?>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="profile.css">

</head>
 ....
 ....
```

Now on another page, you could easily:

```
<?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION["user"]) {
  //logged in
  $name = $_SESSION["user"]["name"];
} else {
  //not logged in
}
?>
<html>
....
....
```

Comment: So the first code snippet is used on the login page and then any other page I use the second code snippet?

Comment: Yes exactly, Use the second one on top of all pages you want to implement login